# Remove synchronized key word from a function using reflection

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection

I use a third party to edit articles on Wikipedia. The library have a function declared like this :

```
public synchronized writeContent(...) {
    //code
}
```

I want to use many threads that will call this method but this method can't be executed by more than one thread at time. They did it like this to prevent people doing many request to the server and excuting it by many threads will not leads to errors.

Can I modify this method to remove synchronized key word using reflection. I can just download the source code and change but I want kept updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you can't.

If you have a look at the documentation for [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), you'll see that it has no methods for altering its state, beyond `setAccessible()`, which doesn't help you.

Reflection will allow you to inspect, and to get to things you wouldn't otherwise be able to get to, but not to make this kind of alteration.

But it is almost certainly a synchronized method for a reason...